Artifactory-cpp-ce - "Unsupported operation: federated" after upgrade to latest version
After I upgraded my artifactory-cpp-ce (conan version) from 7.10.6 to 7.98.8, I started seen a new error in the logs that looks like: 2024-11-15T12:27:58.199Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [1c6a13511b3b7426] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-10] - Unsupported operation: federated
I tried looking for answers but there is ablsolutely no mention of this federated operation anywhere.
The system still works fine from what I can tell but this error appears every 30 seconds-ish which fills up the log file quite quickly.
I'm running this on a Debian 10.
In addition to the error there is also the following backtrace:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported operation: federated
    at org.artifactory.repo.DefaultFederationClientServiceImpl.federationNodeExistsInTopology(DefaultFederationClientServiceImpl.java:181)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.general.GlobalStateProviderServiceImpl.decorateRtfsMigrationNeeded(GlobalStateProviderServiceImpl.java:199)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.general.GlobalStateProviderServiceImpl.triggerCacheUpdateProcessIfNeeded(GlobalStateProviderServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.general.GlobalStateProviderServiceImpl.getGlobalStateAndMessages(GlobalStateProviderServiceImpl.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.service.general.GetGlobalStateService.execute(GetGlobalStateService.java:45)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.ServiceExecutor.process(ServiceExecutor.java:39)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.resource.BaseResource.runService(BaseResource.java:189)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.general.GeneralScreenResource.getGlobalState(GeneralScreenResource.java:71)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:229)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$2(ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.PropsAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(PropsAuthenticationFilter.java:134)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.model.ArtifactoryFilterHolderImpl.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilterHolderImpl.java:48)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.doFilter(ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.authenticateAndExecute(AccessFilter.java:459)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:304)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryProbesFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryProbesFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.artifactory.throttling.qrl.service.QueryRateLimiterServiceImpl.wrapRequestWithLowPriority(QueryRateLimiterServiceImpl.java:438)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryTracingFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryTracingFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciate.

Looks like it might be a bug. I'll forward this internally to our dev team (I work at JFrog). I'll update once I have any more information.

same problem here. using the artifactory-oss helm chart v107.98.8 (7.98.8)

This is indeed a harmless bug and will be fixed in one of the upcoming Artifactory releases. Thx for reporting it! Once I know the release versions, I'll come back to update.

@EldadAssis I think you should post this as an answer. Also, if there's a public Jira ticket available on this, please provide an URL to it.
